# $(f(A))^c\subset f(A^c)$ if $f $ is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $f$ is surjective then $(f(A))^c\subset f(A^c)$.

After drawing a picture I came up with the following proof:

There can be an $A$ so that $\exists x\in A^c$ such that $f(x)=y\in f(A^c)$ but $y\notin (f(A))^c$

The last would work as counterexample of  $(f(A))^c= f(A^c)$.

However I was not able to prove the inclusion  $(f(A))^c\subset f(A^c)$.

**Question:**

How should I prove the inclusion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $f:X\rightarrow Y$ for the function, where $A\subseteq X$. Let $y\in (f(A))^{c}$ be given and note that $(f(A))^{c}=Y\backslash f(A)$. Since $f$ is surjective there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. We conclude that $x\notin A$ because if $x\in A$ then $y=f(x)\in f(A)$, which contradicts the fact that $y\in Y\backslash f(A)$. Hence $x\in X\backslash A$ and we note that $A^{c}=X\backslash A$ to conclude that $y=f(x)\in f(A^{c})$, whence $(f(A))^{c}\subseteq f(A^{c})$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjection and let $A\subseteq X$. We
go to prove that $\left(f(A)\right)^{c}\subseteq f(A^{c})$.

Proof: Let $y\in\left(f(A)\right)^{c}$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is
surjective, there exists $x$$\in X$ such that $y=f(x)$. If $x\in A$,
then $y\in f(A)$ which contradicts to the condition that $y\in\left(f(A)\right)^{c}$
. Therefore, $x\notin A$. That is, $x\in A^{c}$. Therefore $y=f(x)\in f(A^{c})$.
QED.

Comment: How ca this be true " If $x\in A$,
then $y\in f(A)$ which conducts to the condition that $y\in\left(f(A)\right)^{c}$"? If the later quoted expression was true $f$ would not be a function, right?

Comment: typo. It should be contradicts. Thx